# How to dynamically choose the action filter to execute for a Web API Action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, action-filter

I have a API Action that will get requests from two different clients and these two clients will have different authentication mechanisms.

For these two authentication mechanisms I have implemented two action filters. Now I will add these action filters in the API action which will return the same data to both the clients.

I want the code to dynamically choose between the two action filters with respect to the clients. How can I do this ?

I got the below solution. This will go into both action and will check the client and ignore further process whichever is not needed.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1570772.aspx

But I am not sure if this is the only way or do we have a better way for this.

Thanks,
R. Venkatesan

Comment: I'm not sure if there is another way to do this. When I've done something like this I always used this method and it works fine.

Comment: Ivan, Thanks. I too searched and couldn't find any other solution and I am going by this way.